# ¿Como obtener todos lo registros de una tabla junto con la sum de un campo de una de sus relaciones? Laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo dos modelos `Transaction` y `Account`, necesito traer todas las cuentas, o sea `Account::all()` pero adicionarles la suma del campo `amount` de sus **transacciones relacionadas**. Intente con una **subquery** de esta manera:

```php
$accounts = Account::latest()
->withCount('transactions')
->addSelect([
    'total' => Transaction::select('amount')
    ->whereColumn('account_id', 'accounts.id')
    ->sum('amount')
])->get();
```

Lo que claramente es erróneo, porque me arroja la siguiente excepción SQL: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accounts.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select sum('amount') as aggregate from 'transactions' where 'account_id' = 'accounts'.'id')`

Estoy muy confundido sobre si es posible, y como puedo hacerlo; no se por que me da ese error

No se mucho del uso de **subquerys** así que, les agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Prueba con algo así, a ver si es lo que buscas: `Account::withCount(['transactions as total' => function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('sum(amount)'));
}])->get();`.

Comment: Perfectooo..!!! funciono mil gracias, ¿puedes agregarlo como respuesta y explicando un poco lo que hace? para futuras vistas a la pregunta y para saber mejor yo también que es lo que hace esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien en el comentario te propuse modificar el método `withCount()` para obtener la suma de una de las columnas de los registros relacionados:

```
Account::withCount(['transactions as total' => function($query) {     
    $query->select(DB::raw('sum(amount)')); 
}])->get()
```

Fué porque recordaba haberlo hecho así en algún proyecto (puedes seguir la lógica que aplica ese método a partir de [esta función](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d9b43ee080b4d51344b2e578aa667f85040471a2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L450) de Eloquent).

Si bien en la documentación [Aggregating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models) no está explícito, sí nos dá una pista al mencionar

> If you need to set additional query constraints on the count query, you may pass an array keyed by the relationships you wish to count. The array values should be closures which receive the query builder instance.

> Si necesita establecer restricciones de consulta adicionales en la consulta de count, puede pasar una matriz codificada por las relaciones que desea contar. Los valores de la matriz deben ser funciones anónimas que reciban la instancia del query builder.

Entonces, podemos aprovechar esa función anónima para modificar la instancia de query builder para que en vez de tomar los valores por default (que usarían el agregado 'count'), y pasarle la subconsulta que queremos hacer, que es 'sum' de una columna.

---

Pero al buscar argumentos para escribir la explicación de esta respuesta, me encontré que a partir de laravel 8.x, también disponemos del método [withSum()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions), por lo que también podrías hacer simplemente:

```
Account::withSum('transactions', 'amount')->get();
```

Y obtendrías un campo `transactions_sum_amount` en cada instancia del modelo `Account`.

Comment: Perfecto, seguiré con la lógica planteada en tu comentario, ya que como mencione estoy usando **Laravel 7**; ya conocía la existencia de `withSum()` pero luego me di cuenta que no estaba disponible para mi, muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Ahh.. ok. Entonces agregué lo que estaba escribiendo como explicación para versiones anteriores. Si revisas el código de los otros agregados, verás que también podrías modificarlos como para hacerte tu propio withSum(), y si quieres darle una vueltita más de rosca, te puedes hacer un [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes) para tus modelos y dejar las consultas más "limpias".

Comment: Muy bieeennn..!! de nuevo gracias :D